# Multiple iterations of a script involving a NodeList

Tags: javascript, html

I'm replacing an element with the class 'custom' with a div element that has the 'hidden' class using the code below.

I need it to run multiple iterations of the script for each node in the nodelist. I can't change the 'custom' elements, so I can't assign ID's to them. I realize that I could simply make multiple copies of this script, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

I've done some looking into possible solutions, and I think an array would work? I've never used them in any of my projects.
However, if there is no other way I guess I'll just go with the multiple copies solution.

```
<script> 
 function replaceTargetWith( targetClasses, html ){
   var targetClass = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClasses);
   var i, div, elm, last, target = targetClass[0];
   div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = html;
   i = div.childNodes.length;
   last = target;
   while(i--){
     target.parentNode.insertBefore((elm = div.childNodes[i]), last);
     last = elm;
   }
   target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
}
window.onload = function(){
  replaceTargetWith('custom','<div class="hidden"></div>');  
}
</script>
```

Comment: The key is that `[0]` there. Have you learned how to do "for-loops"?

Comment: I'm familiar with them in regards to Java, are they different in JavaScript?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvdf5n-zI14

Comment: Okay, thanks! Didn't even think of for loops. Would I have to convert the NodeList into an array for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must iterate `targetClasses` instead of just using `targetClasses[0]`.

```js
function replaceTargetWith( targetClasses, html ){
  var parser = document.createElement('div');
  parser.innerHTML = html;
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClasses);
  [].slice.call(targets).forEach(function(target) {
    var parentTarget = target.parentNode;
    [].forEach.call(parser.childNodes, function(child) {
      parentTarget.insertBefore(child.cloneNode(true), target);
    });
    parentTarget.removeChild(target);
  });
}
```

```js
function replaceTargetWith( targetClasses, html ){
  var parser = document.createElement('div');
  parser.innerHTML = html;
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClasses);
  [].slice.call(targets).forEach(function(target) {
    var parentTarget = target.parentNode;
    [].forEach.call(parser.childNodes, function(child) {
      parentTarget.insertBefore(child.cloneNode(true), target);
    });
    parentTarget.removeChild(target);
  });
}
replaceTargetWith('custom', '<div class="hidden">Hidden</div>');
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
```

Also consider [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
function replaceTargetWith( targetClasses, html ){
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClasses);
  [].slice.call(targets).forEach(function(target) {
    target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
  });
}
```

```js
function replaceTargetWith( targetClasses, html ){
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClasses);
  [].slice.call(targets).forEach(function(target) {
    target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
  });
}
replaceTargetWith('custom', '<div class="hidden">Hidden</div>');
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
<div class="custom">Custom</div>
```

Comment: The first solution works perfectly! I'll look into both solutions however.